# jQuery & jQuery UI code not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have jquery UI and jQuery linked on my page, and I have the following jQuery UI code currently on the page:

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "parent"});
    });
```

I want to have this jquery code run below the code above:

```
function new() {  
    $("p").append("<strong>Hello</strong>");
}
```

But for some reason it's not working when both are in the same place and as a newbie to jQuery, I'm not sure what's wrong (both of the codes were mostly copied and pasted from the site). I suspect it's something to do with the function statement.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "it's not working"? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @brianpeiris I expect both parts of the code to run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new` is a [reserved keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) in javascript (it's used as syntax to create new objects) so you can't use it as a function name. Try using a different name for your function, for example:

```
function mynew() {  
    $("p").append("<strong>Hello</strong>");
}
```

Comment: By the way, you now have enough reputation to give upvotes, so conside also upvoting my answer (up arrow) if you are happy with it :-)

Comment: Bonus question: Why does appending this prevent the .draggable function from working: $("body").append("<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <br>
    <textarea id="contents" cols="20" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>");

Comment: @lawm You need to initialize the draggable after you append it to the document.

Comment: Maybe because it doesn't have a parent div to be used for your 'containement' parameter? not sure.. you better create a http://jsfiddle.net that demonstrate your problem so it's easier for people to help you..

Comment: Okay, here: http://jsfiddle.net/MJKhq/2/ (look for the comment in the <script> section

Comment: You were not escaping your html double quotes inside your append function, I used just single quotes to make it work, see a working version of your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MJKhq/3/

Comment: Okay, so, so, sorry for being so annoying, but my last question (you don't have to answer it if you don't want to): Is there a way to make the appended elements draggable too?

Comment: Yes, you just have to make sure you append elements to your `#draggable` div (rather than the body page), see http://jsfiddle.net/MJKhq/5/